# Google Api login as Brand Account - Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-plus

I try to create simple webapp with Singing as Google Account. My Javascript code to login:

```
gapi.load('auth2', function(){
            // Retrieve the singleton for the GoogleAuth library and set up the client.
            vm.auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
                client_id: 'XXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com',
                scope:'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me'
            });

            vm.auth2.attachClickHandler(document.getElementById("google-login-button"), {},
                function(googleUser) {
                    var user = googleUser.getBasicProfile();

                }, function(error) {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(error, undefined, 2));
                });
        });
```

But when i click on button to login google account, i can select Google account, but I Can't select google `Brand Account`.
 In Google Console i Enable Google+ Api.  What i do wrong?

Comment: Not all branded accounts support it i dont think what type is it?

Comment: for example : wordpress has plugin `jetpack` , when i click `connect with google plus` in first i select google account, then i select google plus account. In My login app i click Connect - but i can select only google account. I found problem, my Google login url  not have parametr `delegation=1`, but i dont know, how can i add this. :/